# Use single variable to define mustache tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, mustache

Is there any option to set mustache tag with some define variables? Something like this:

Json

```
{
    "color_set_01": [
        "white", "black"
        ],
    "color_set_02": [
        "green", "red"
    ]
}
```

JavaScript

```
var color = 'color_set_' + options.number;

$.getJSON('json/data.json', function(data) {
    var template = "<ul>{{color}}<li class="{{.}}"></li>{{/color}}</ul>";
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    colors_panel.html(html);
});
```

and desired result if it's `color_set_01` aray

```
<div class="colors_panel">
    <ul>
      <li class="white">
      <li class="black">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The edit changes the question a lot for me, but I am still unsure what you are trying to get with the `color_class`

Comment: `color_class` will be my colors in specify arays... thats why i use list

Comment: but if you have a list of strings, and i guess one of them is "super_green"? What are you hoping to get from that? Can you show what you expect `html` to be after the call to `Mustache.to_html()`?

Comment: ok, now it's just like i have in my setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a quick look at http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/tutorial-html-templates-with-mustache-js/, I think this would work:

```
var template = "<ul>{{#"+color+"}}<li class=\"{{.}}\"></li>{{/"+color+"}}</ul>";
```

It seems that the `#` sets up the ability to use a list, the `.` is basically each item of the list. Also, you needed to escape your quotes in the template string.

This also assumes your JSON should look like this:

```
{
    "color_set_01": [
        "white", "black"
    ],
    "color_set_02": [
        "green", "yellow"
    ]
}
```

If there are more than `color_set`s in your JSON, then you'll have to show what the parents of `color_set_01` is up until the top for me to help further.

Comment: I think you aren't showing the full JSON, is there a higher level above the `color_set`s? I'll update my post to show what `mustache` is expecting.

Comment: Okay, but your JSON had each color_set as a separate object. You'll want to reformat as it is in my post.

Comment: now if i set inline (`<ul>{{#color_set_01}}<li class=\"{{.}}\"></li>{{/color_set_01}}</ul>`) in mustache tamplate i have sucsess result but if i use my variable i have empty list :(

Comment: OK, it's work perfectly, i love you man :), much thx for your patience and help, BR and +1 for you